# Generate a new Id column in SQL Server that will be dependent on other 2 id columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to generate a new id column as `IndexID` that will depend on 2 other ids. in my case the 2 other ids are `OrderID` and `PatientOrderID`.

This is my current table structure:

[image: Table Structure]]

In this above image you can see there are 3 rows:
1st row has `OrderID` of 121336 and `PatientOrderID` of 230216
2nd row has `OrderID` of 121337 and `PatientOrderID` of 230217
3rd row has `OrderID` of 121337 and `PatientOrderID` of 230218

I want to add `IndexId` that will depend on `OrderID` and `PatientOrderID`.

For example:
1st row `IndexID` should be 1
2nd row `IndexID` should be 1
3rd row `IndexId` should be 2

This is because for each `OrderID` the `IndexId` will start at 1 & if there are 2 rows with same `OrderID` then we will check `PatientOrderID` to create the `IndexID` as `1,2` and so on.

Currently I have used `dense_rank` which is not correct in my query so please ignore it.

I am I will be able to make you understand my requirements. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    O.ID  AS OrderID,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.ID AS PatientOrderID,
    dense_rank() over (order by smsFDGPatientOrder.ID ) as IndexID,
    --'Example' AS IndexID,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.Isotope,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.ActualIsotope,
    OS.StatusID StatusID,
    NCS.StatusID AS NoChangeStatusID,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order] AS FDGOrderID,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.ExamDate,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.ActualExamDate,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.Indication,
    smsFDGPatientOrder.[Procedure],
    smsFDGPatientOrder.ActualProcedure
FROM 
    dbo.smsFDGOrder O WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[smsFDGPatientOrder] as smsFDGPatientOrder WITH(NOLOCK) ON smsFDGPatientOrder.[Order] = O.[ID]
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 OS.StatusID 
     FROM dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus OS  WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE OS.FDGOrder = O.ID 
     ORDER BY OS.TimeAdded DESC, OS.ID DESC) OS
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 OS.StatusID 
     FROM dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus OS  WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE OS.FDGOrder = O.ID  AND OS.StatusID != 3
     ORDER BY OS.TimeAdded DESC, OS.ID DESC) NCS
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.smsStatus S  WITH(NOLOCK) ON S.ID = OS.StatusID
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.smsStatus NOChange WITH(NOLOCK) ON NOChange.ID = NCS.StatusID
WHERE 
    (S.Status IN ('In Queue'))
     AND (S.Status != 'Changed' OR NOChange.Status IN ('In Queue')) 
ORDER BY  
    O.ID
```

Comment: If possible, please add source data as `insert` script, and append desired result for this data to your question.

Comment: @IvanStarostin

You can use Demo Data with this .

create table #Temp(OrderID int,PatientOrderID int)
insert into #Temp select 121336,230216
insert into #Temp select 121337,230217
insert into #Temp select 121337,230218


select * from #Temp
drop table #Temp

Desired Output is generating the IndexID as per my requirements (read requirements) .

OrderID PatientOrderID IndexID
121336 230216                 1
121337 230217                 1
121337 230218                 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row_number () over (partition by O.Id order by smsFDGPatientOrder.Id) as IndexId
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have your requirements right, you are right to use `dense_rank`.  You just need to add a little extra logic:

```
cast(dense_rank() over (order by OrderID) as nvarchar(10))
        + case when dense_rank() over (order by PatientOrderID) > 1
                then N',' + cast(dense_rank() over (partition by OrderID order by PatientOrderID) as nvarchar(10))
                else N''
                end as IndexID
```

Which will output `1` for the first `OrderID` and then `1,2`, `1,3`, etc for any additional `PatientOrderID` values in the same `OrderID`:

```
OrderID PatientOrderID  IndexID
121336  230216          1
121337  230217          2,1
121337  230218          2,2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it was not my requirements. @Lord Peter's answer helped me . just needed that  partition by which i did not think. Also your answer was returning like 
1
2,2
2,3